# How to deny access to a page in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have a login page (login.html) where users will provide a username and password.

When they click the submit button, that data is sent to a servlet (LoginServlet) that verifies the user/pass (using a DB). If the user is "authenticated", it redirects them to another page (index.html).

However, anyone can gain access to that page regardless of the sign-in feature by just going to the link directly.

With Servlets/JSPs, there are easy counter-measures in place to prevent unauthorized access (check the session/cookie), but with plain old HTML pages, there isn't quite an easy measure that I know of.

Can anyone suggest a good method for going about this?

Comment: You can't do it in HTML, obviously, which is why JSP/ASP/PHP and so on were invented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Filters for intercepting all requests to your web server. Refer the following [link](http://www.developer.com/security/article.php/3467801/Securing-J2EE-Applications-with-a-Servlet-Filter.htm)

Also dont serve plain html documents directly, use filter-mapping to redirect requests for all html pages to first go via a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Servlet containers provide mechanisms for handling this sort of security configuration. Use them rather than rolling your own.